# Delphi PATH error on Android compiler

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have just installed Delphi 10 Seattle in a DELL workstation of my office and I am able to compile 32 bit and 64 bit. When I select Android I have this kind of error:

> [Exec Error] The command "PATH C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\InterBase\redist\InterBaseXE7\IDE_spoof;C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\bin; [... more lines ...];exited with code 1.

I guessed that this was a misconfiguration and so I have checked the IDE options. As you can see I have no warnings: [check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY7Vc.png).

As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6EOP.png) the path specified in the IDE is correct. What else could it be? I hope I have provided everything. Should I try to delete and add again the SDK version?

The entire error message is here if needed:

```
[Exec Error] The command "PATH C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\InterBase\redist\InterBaseXE7\IDE_spoof;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Bpl;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Bpl\Win64;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\ & "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\25.0.2\dx.bat" --dex --output="C:\Users\defaulr.user\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\Android\Debug\classes.dex" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\lib\Android\Debug\android-support-v4.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\lib\Android\Debug\apk-expansion.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\lib\Android\Debug\cloud-messaging.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\lib\Android\Debug\fmx.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-analytics-v2.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-billing.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-licensing.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-services.dex.jar" " exited with code 1.
```

Comment: Try adding to the PATH the location of SDK Manager.

Comment: so I should add the location of the SDK manager in C:\Programs\Android or the SDK manager in Embarcadero's folder?

Comment: Try to add it to the System path.

Comment: It might be that the SDK is not installed, have a look in Tools|Platforms|Additional

Answer (score 2):

I have installed RAD Studio on a Windows 10 machine and I had no problems. From the other side, I have installed RAD in 2 win 7 machines and I have had the same problem.

I went to `C:\Users\myUserName\Documents\Embarcadero\` and I have deleted this folder (the one that contains the project folder). Then I updated the PATH variable and restarted the IDE. Now I am able to compile on Android as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is probably too late but I had the same issue. And found one of the possible solution. Here it is.

Got [Exec Error] The command "PATH C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161.... Error 1.
while trying to compile for Android in Delphi Rio.

I finally traced the batch files to see waht they were doing: finding the Java utilities on the disk.

I decided to clean the whole set of Java stuff on the machine and to use the latest java machine, the latest SDK in 32 and in 64 bits.

I updated the path in the configuration
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\KeyTool.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\JarSigner.exe

This allowed me to compile

But ... I am not out of it.
- the app which was working fine in Tokyo version fails in Rio (database issue on mobile)
- Android 8.0.0 does not allow debugging for the moment (needs 8.1). Contacted Samsung.
- my tablet is too old for the Android version (4.4).
- the PATH variable was too long with the 2 versions (Tokyo & Rio) installed. I had to extract the delphi parts in a batch.

So still a lot to do to come back to the point where I was before Rio ...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, until I'am uninstall the all java SDK, and install it from the Rad Studio: Tools\Manage Platforms...
After Manage window popup switch the Additional Options and check the Java Development Kit 1.8
After installed (in reality just downloaded), install from the downloaded path:
c:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\CatalogRepository\1.8-JDK8-20.0.36039.7899\ (or something similar)
After really installed, set the correct paths in SDK Manager.
Tools/Options/Deployment/SDK Manager/
select Android SDK version and set the correct patchs like in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DXtU_8QdVE

Comment: Consider reformatting this text. Also please clearly state that the problem was resolved after you reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error after I had started a project as a Win project and then tried to compile it as an Android app.