# Delphi android java path error

Tags: delphi

I have a problem which is this:

[image]

It's different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41939719/delphi-path-error-on-android-compiler). Delphi was working fine but then I removed the jdk 1.8.0 and I have installed the jdk 1.9.0 because I have to work with IntelliJ IDEA (Java).

Delphi (android) is not working anymore because I've removed ( = uninstalled) the 1.8.0 jdk. How do I fix the problem? How can I tell Delphi to use the new 1.9.0 JDK?

---

I am using Delphi Tokyo. I have edited the windows `PATH` variable adding the path to the jdk (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1) but it's not working.

Comment: It might help to have a complete error message in text, rather than a picture of part of it. Have you restarted the IDE after altering the PATH?

Comment: Did you update the settings in **Tools->Options->SDK Manager** (specifically the entries in the **NDK** tab in that dialog) to point to the proper locations as well? It's  not enough just to change the system PATH.

Comment: @KenWhite that was the solution, I did that and it worked!